# Facebook Bundle and Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::serialize() must return a string or NULL

Tags: facebook, serialization, symfony

I've follow the doc of the bundle (tagged version to work with symfony 2.012):

http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle

So i've got this error when i intend to log on my website now :

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::serialize() must return a string or NULL

I the logon with facebook work but it's doesn't log me on my website here is my configs files :

//security.yml

```
security:
factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"
providers:

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
       id: my.facebook.user    

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: .*
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/psiware/"
            server_url: "http://localhost/keepinsport/web/app_dev.php/ks"
            login_path: ^/login
            check_path: ^/login_check$
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        form_login:
            provider:     fos_userbundle
            login_path:   /login
            use_forward:  false
            check_path:   /login_check
            failure_path: null
            default_target_path: /ks
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
            handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"] 
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
          key:      aSecretKey
          #Correspond à un mois
          lifetime: 2592000
          path:     /
          domain:   ~           

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512


# C'est ici que tout se passe : qui a accès à quoi ?
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$,          role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$,     role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting,  role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/,     role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/ks,         role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/facebook/,  role: [ROLE_FACEBOOK] }
    - { path: ^/.*,         role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

//my config.yml

```
fos_facebook:
file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
alias:  facebook
app_id: 106071199501870
secret: 219af5b2792ea6267de3cf1017f91c1a
cookie: true
permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]

services:
my.facebook.user:
    class: Ks\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
    arguments:
        facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
        validator: "@validator"
```

//My login.html.twig

```
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
{{ facebook_login_button({'autologoutlink': true}) }}
 <script>
    function goLogIn(){
        window.location = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
    }

    function onFbInit() {
        if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
            setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
        } else {
            window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_logout') }}";
        }
    }
</script>
```

//My User entity

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $lastname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="facebookId", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $facebookId;

public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array($this->facebookID, parent::serialize()));
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    list($this->facebookID, $parentData) = unserialize($data);
    parent::unserialize($parentData);
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->firstname;
}

/**
 * @param string $firstname
 */
public function setFirstname($firstname)
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

/**
 * @param string $lastname
 */
public function setLastname($lastname)
{
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
}

/**
 * Get the full name of the user (first + last name)
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastname();
}

/**
 * @param string $facebookId
 * @return void
 */
public function setFacebookId($facebookId)
{
    $this->facebookId = $facebookId;
    $this->setUsername($facebookId);
    $this->salt = '';
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFacebookId()
{
    return $this->facebookId;
}

/**
 * @param Array
 */
public function setFBData($fbdata)
{
    if (isset($fbdata['id'])) {
        $this->setFacebookId($fbdata['id']);
        $this->addRole('ROLE_FACEBOOK');
    }
    if (isset($fbdata['first_name'])) {
        $this->setFirstname($fbdata['first_name']);
    }
    if (isset($fbdata['last_name'])) {
        $this->setLastname($fbdata['last_name']);
    }
    if (isset($fbdata['email'])) {
        $this->setEmail($fbdata['email']);
    }
}
```

//My facebookProvider.php

```
class FacebookProvider implements UserProviderInterface
```

{
    /**
     * @var \Facebook
     */
    protected $facebook;
    protected $userManager;
    protected $validator;

```
public function __construct(BaseFacebook $facebook, $userManager, $validator)
{
    $this->facebook = $facebook;
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $this->userManager->supportsClass($class);
}

public function findUserByFbId($fbId)
{
    return $this->userManager->findUserBy(array('facebookId' => $fbId));
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $user = $this->findUserByFbId($username);

    try {
        $fbdata = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $fbdata = null;
    }

    if (!empty($fbdata)) {
        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $user->setPassword('');
        }

        // TODO use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime
        $user->setFBData($fbdata);

        if (count($this->validator->validate($user, 'Facebook'))) {
            // TODO: the user was found obviously, but doesnt match our expectations, do something smart
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('The facebook user could not be stored');
        }
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException('The user is not authenticated on facebook');
    }

    return $user;
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($user)) || !$user->getFacebookId()) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
    }

    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getFacebookId());
}
```

}

I don't understand why the serialisation doesnt work thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Symfony are you using? For Symfony 2.0.X you need the branch 2.0, not master.
Check the bundle documentation (this is the branch 2.0 one):

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/2.0/README.md

Answer (score 0):

In `security.yml` `check_path` should not be same for `form_login` and `fos_facebook` providers.